# how to change the text of a button in a Jquery on click event handler inside an ajax success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I usually figure things out for myself but this one is giving me a really difficult time. I need to change the text value of a button in a table that is created by php from a database, after it gets clicked on.

```
        <td id="order_num"><?php echo $order -> order_num; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order -> data; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order -> data; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order -> data; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order -> data; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order -> data; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order -> data; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order -> data; ?></td>

        <!-- **** this is the button. ******** -->          
        <td><button type="submit" class="accept_order" id ="row_<?php echo $order -> order_num; ?>" 
        data-row_id = "row_<?php echo $order -> order_num; ?>" data-current_user = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>" 
        data-order_num = "<?php echo $order -> order_num; ?>">Accept</button>
```

here is the big mess of an ajax call

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.shop').on('click', 'button', function(e){

```
        var button = $(this).find('button'); //trying to put the value of the current button in a variable to pass to the ajax function.                                        
        var current_user = $(this).closest('.shop').find('.accept_order').data('current_user');
        console.log(current_user);
        var row_id = $(this).closest('.shop').find('.accept_order').data('row_id');


        var accepted_order = $(this).closest('.shop').find('.accept_order').data('order_num');
        console.log(accepted_order);
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax('url', {
            type: "POST",

            data: { order_id: accepted_order, user_id: current_user },
            success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
                console.log(this);
                //change the text of the button to something like "accepted"

                ***************this is where I have problems ***********************
                $(this).html('accepted'); or
                $(this).closest('.shop').find('button').html(msg); or
                button.text(msg);



            },
            error: function(){
                 $(this).closest('.shop').find('.accept_order').html("failure");
            }
        });


    });
});

</script>
```

I did use $('button').html(msg); 
but that changes all of the buttons. It seems like I lose scope to the object when inside the success function. Any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found your problem source but I'm not sure. And The problem came from `this` keyword because `this` in the ajax function direct to the ajax object not the button node object. So you can use `bind` function in the success and error functions to make `this` directs to the button. here is the modification:

and another thing the **url** in ajax function is a variable not a string as you wrote above.

```
$.ajax(url, {
        type: "POST",
        data: { order_id: accepted_order, user_id: current_user },
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            console.log(this);
            //change the text of the button to something like "accepted"

            ***************this is where I have problems ***********************
            $(this).html('accepted'); or
            $(this).closest('.shop').find('button').html(msg); or
            button.text(msg);



        }.bind(this),
        error: function(){
             $(this).closest('.shop').find('.accept_order').html("failure");
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

I'm not sure from the solution because there is no demo for what you asked about.

I hope it works.

Comment: Your a genius, thanks so much. I have been working on this for days lol. I kinda had a feeling that the "this" was different.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the class to select the button

```
    $.ajax('url', {
        type: "POST",

        data: { order_id: accepted_order, user_id: current_user },
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            console.log(this);
            //change the text of the button to something like "accepted"

            ***************this is where I have problems ***********************
            $("button.accept_order").html(msg);



        },
        error: function(){
             $(this).closest('.shop').find('.accept_order').html("failure");
        }
    });
```

or better..

```
var button = $(this);
```

and inside your ajax call just use:

```
button.html(msg);
```